# The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the followng method:-

```
public ActionResult CustomersDetails(string[] SelectRight)
{
    var selectedCustomers = new SelectedCustomers
    {
        Info = SelectRight.Select(GetAccount)
    };

    return View(selectedCustomers);
}

private AccountDefinition GetAccount(string id)
{
    return entities.AccountDefinition.Find(id);
}
```

but it is returning the following error:-

```
The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details.
```

On the `return entities.AccountDefinition.Find(id);` line

So what is causing this error?

The inner exception is:-

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details.
Parameter name: keyValues
  Source=EntityFramework
  ParamName=keyValues
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindInStore(WrappedEntityKey key, String keyValuesParamName)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)

  InnerException: System.Data.EntitySqlException
       HResult=-2146232006
       Message=The argument types 'Edm.Int64' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 90.
       Source=System.Data.Entity
       Column=90
       ErrorContext=WHERE predicate, line 1, column 90
       ErrorDescription=The argument types 'Edm.Int64' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation.
       Line=1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the exception message `The argument types 'Edm.Int64' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 90.`.

This implies that the `ID` of your `AccountDefinition` class is a `long` or `Int64` however you are trying to query it using a `string`.

You need to do one of the following:

1. Change `string[]` in `CustomersDetails(string[] SelectRight)` to `long[]` and `string` in `GetAccount(string id)` to `long id`
2. Change `return entities.AccountDefinition.Find(id);` to `return entities.AccountDefinition.Find(long.Parse(id));`

Option 1 is the better option but will require more change (which I would recommend you do), Option 2 is less change but has the possibility it will blow up if `id` is null or a value which cannot be parsed to a `long`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I figured I'd add a comment here since I had the same problem.

All I did was re-arrange the parameters in the find function.

I had it like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(Int32 id, string dataSource)
        {
            TVData_VW_ShowList tvdata_vw_showlist = context.TVData_VW_ShowList.Find(id, datasource);
            if (tvdata_vw_showlist == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tvdata_vw_showlist);
        }
```

And I had to change it to this:

```
public ActionResult Details(Int32 id, string dataSource)
        {
            TVData_VW_ShowList tvdata_vw_showlist = context.TVData_VW_ShowList.Find(dataSource, id);
            if (tvdata_vw_showlist == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tvdata_vw_showlist);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have invested lot of time in solving this issue but at last found that the Sequence of Keys in .Find(Key1, Key2, ..) should match with the sequence of keys in Edmx diagram entity.

Answer (score 0):

You pass to Find method string but expeced Int64 `The argument types 'Edm.Int64' and 'Edm.String'`.