# How to retrieving information without using primary key asp.net c#?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a Login for a site using asp.net C# MVC. So here is my view (UserLogin.cshtml) file looks like.

```
    @model FoodieWeb.Models.UsersModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserLogin";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@*<h2>UserLogin</h2>*@

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("UserLogin", "UserLogin", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @*@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Username." />
                        @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Username." />
                        @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @*@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)*@

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "UserRegister", "UserRegister")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                    </p>*@
            }
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @*<section id="socialLoginForm">
                @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
            </section>*@
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.UsersModelID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")*@
</p>
```

And here is my Model (UsersModel.cs) looks like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FoodieWeb.Models
{
    [Table("User")]
    public class UsersModel
    {
        public int UsersModelID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([\w-\._\+%]+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,6})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email")]
        public string email { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-za-z]+[\s]{1}[A-za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+))$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter lowercase & uppercase letters only")]
        public string fname { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-za-z]+[\s]{1}[A-za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+))$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter lowercase & uppercase letters only")]
        public string lname { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([\(]{1}[0-9]{3}[\)]{1}[\.| |\-]{0,1}|^[0-9]{3}[\.|\-| ]?)?[0-9]{3}(\.|\-| )?[0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number")]
        public string phone { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-za-z]+[\s]{1}[A-za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+))$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter lowercase & uppercase letters only")]
        public string address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-za-z]+[\s]{1}[A-za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+))$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter lowercase & uppercase letters only")]

        public string city { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "PostalCode is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number")]

        public Nullable<decimal> postcode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "District is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-za-z]+[\s]{1}[A-za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+))$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter lowercase & uppercase letters only")]

        public string district { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Type is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-za-z]+[\s]{1}[A-za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+))$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter lowercase & uppercase letters only")]

        public string user_type { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
        public System.DateTime created_date { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm password is required")]
        [Compare("password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password does not match")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string confirm_password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Nullable<bool> agree { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And also my Controller (UserLogin.cs) looks like this.

```
using FoodieWeb.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FoodieWeb.Controllers
{
    public class UserLoginController : Controller
    {
        private UsersModelContext db = new UsersModelContext();
        // GET: UserLogin
        public ActionResult UserLogin()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UserLogin(UsersModel usersModel)
        {
            string email = Request.Form["email"];
            string password = Request.Form["password"];

            UsersModel users = db.UsersModel.Find(email);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if ((email.Equals(usersModel.email)) && (password.Equals(usersModel.password)))
                {
                    Session["Email"] = email;
                    Session["LoggedIn"] = "yes";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("~/Views/UserLogin/UserLogin.cshtml");
                }
            }
            return View(usersModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UserLogOff()
        {
            //AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedIn"] = null;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        public object[] UsersModelID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Within my controller there is an error which i cannot solve. That means in my model class i have used UserModelID as the primary key. But here i'm retrieving the details of a particular user in this way.

string email = Request.Form["email"];
string password = Request.Form["password"];

UsersModel users = db.UsersModel.Find(email);

But email is not my primary key. Since that it will give me an error when login to the site. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: And if you try: users=db.UserModel.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.email==email)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UsersModel users = db.UsersModel.FirstOrDefault(m => m.email == email)

Answer (score 0):

db.Find(key) will only use the primary key to find the entity, you could try using db.UsersModel.FirstOrDefault. This could return null, make sure you check for null before trying to use the returned entity e.g. as in the code below.

```js
using FoodieWeb.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FoodieWeb.Controllers
{
    public class UserLoginController : Controller
    {
        private UsersModelContext db = new UsersModelContext();
        // GET: UserLogin
        public ActionResult UserLogin()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UserLogin(UsersModel usersModel)
        {
            string email = Request.Form["email"];
            string password = Request.Form["password"];

            UsersModel users = db.UsersModel.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.email==email);
            if (ModelState.IsValid&&users!=null)
            {

                if ((email.Equals(users.email)) && (password.Equals(users.password)))
                {
                    Session["Email"] = email;
                    Session["LoggedIn"] = "yes";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("~/Views/UserLogin/UserLogin.cshtml");
                }
            }
            return View(usersModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UserLogOff()
        {
            //AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedIn"] = null;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        public object[] UsersModelID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is also give me the following exception

Comment: The argument types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 82.

Comment: Have you tried debuging through stepping over each line in the UserLogin method, maybe the problem is not in the UserLogin method's code block

Comment: The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details.

Comment: Yes i have tried debugging. But unfortunately i couldn't find the error exactly.

Comment: Ok, seems this error is related to your model context. Check out this link which should help solve the error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014271/the-type-of-one-of-the-primary-key-values-did-not-match-the-type-defined-in-the

Comment: try checking enywhere you are using Find e.g. db.UsersModel.Find(email) and make sure the parameter's datatype you are passing to it matches the primary key's datatype in the db e.g. if the datatype of the UsersModel table primay key is an int, you pass an int to the find method, if it is a string, you pass a string e.t.c