# The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to grab some ids in an array and then to select some of them. My table id field has values as 01, 02, 01-03-04 so I thought,  first to use regex to remove the dash and then to convert it to int. My field is navchar. I dont know if that is correct but I need values that are greater than 01 and smaller than 08.

This is what I have done so far

```
var tids = db.mytable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(p => Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(p.myID, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty)))
    .ToArray();


var query = (from e in tids
             where e >= 1 && e <= 8
             select new MyTableViewModel ()
             {
                 ID = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(db.mytable.Find(e).myID, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty)),
                 Details= db.mytable.Find(e).myDetails
             }).ToList();
```

and the to pass the data in a list so to create a dropdown menu

```
SelectList list = new SelectList(query , "ID", "Details"); 
ViewBag.ddl = list;
```

My MyTableViewModel

```
public class MyTableViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

But I get

> "The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity"

and in the InnerException

> "The argument types 'Edm.String' and 'Edm.Int32' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 66."

I have seen this [The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014271/the-type-of-one-of-the-primary-key-values-did-not-match-the-type-defined-in-the)

but no luck

thank you

Comment: `db.mytable.Find(e).myID` translates to `db.mytable.Find(1).myID` but it would need to be `db.mytable.Find("01").myID`

Comment: What are the types `Edm.String` and `Edm.Int32`? Are they standard .NET types?

Comment: so @StephenMuecke  do you think that I have to remove Regex? All my values in the array have become 1,2,20103 etc....the first 0 and the dash have been removed....

Comment: @touinta, What percentage of the records in the db will have values that do not match? And what you probably want is a `db.mytable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replacex.myID, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty)) >= 1 && x => Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replacex.myID, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty)) <= 8).Select(x => new MyTableViewModel{ ... });`

Comment: I get error near Replace. I tried `Regex.Replace(x.myID, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty)` but no luck

Comment: @touinta - sorry that was a typo

Comment: I correct it! it works thank you!!!